# How do I create a simple button without using the Interface builder?

Tags: iphone, user-interface

How do I create a simple button without using the Interface builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below

```
UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
playButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
[playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:playButton];
```

Comment: [self.view addSubview:playButton];Here it is showing error like request for member view in something not in a structure or union

Comment: @Ammu : In Which class (UIView OR UIViewController) you are creating the  UIButton ..

Comment: @Ammu: bracket is mismatched in first line ... and should be  UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] ;

Answer (score 2):

You would need to declare a UIButton like this:

```
UIButton *newButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40)];
[newButton setTitle:@"Some Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You would then add the button to a view -

```
[self.view addSubview: newButton]; // (could be another view other then self.view)
```

And finally, if you want some action to occur when pressing that button, you would add:

```
[newButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and of course declare that function:

```
- (void) doSomething
{
       NSLog(@"Button pressed");
}
```

And of course don't forget to release the button.

Comment: your button (newButton) is leaking - add [newButton release]; after adding the action;

Comment: yes I know, that's why I wrote the "And of course don't forget to release the button." at the end :)

Answer (score 1):

like this-

custom button -

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f)];
```

system buttom -

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Comment: UIButton *bt1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 0, 0)];
 [bt1 setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [bt1 release];

Comment: you also need to add it on your view [self.windows addSubview:button];